# MS Access: Can the Unbound-continous form shows blank row like the bound form?

Tags: recordset, unbound

i'm trying to build a main/sub-form that get data from user and save them to two tables.

```
 "Save" should be done ONLY when a "save button" is clicked.
```

I've tried the "bound forms" but they insert data to tables when they loose focus.
so i'm trying the "unbound forms" using "recordset".


**My question is:** 
 
Can the "unbound sub form" shows a new-blank row when (lets say) last field in the current row is updated with data ?

Same as bound continuous form does

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your form/subform is unbound, then it will not update any information in any table unless you run a query. Otherwise, the unbound form will only update the fields on the form and clear all data when the form is closed.

Comment: Thanks Chris. i just want the form to view a blank record below the currently in use record. Not saving in database.  The bound-continuous form views that blank record . is it possible to do that with unbound-continous form ?